# "+ can not have such operands in this context." error ( VHDL CODE)

Tags: addition, vhdl, operands

> - can not have such operands in this context

Can someone tell me what is wrong and how to fix it please?

I tried to search the problem on the internet, *why can't I add to STD_LOGIC_VECTOR* and I didn't find anything that explains right my problem. So here I am asking you guys what's the problem?

```
entity Modes is
    Port ( RST : in  STD_LOGIC;
           CLK_33MHZ : in  STD_LOGIC;
           BTN : in  STD_LOGIC;
           LED : out  STD_LOGIC);
end Modes;

architecture Behavioral of Modes is

 signal ledstatus : STD_LOGIC;
 signal mode : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0);
 signal modestatus : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);

begin 

 process(CLK_33MHZ,RST)

 variable cnt : integer range 0 to 33000000;

begin

 if(RST = '1') then
    cnt := 0;
    mode <= "00";
    LED <= '0';
    ledstatus <= '0';
     elsif(rising_edge(CLK_33MHZ)) then
        if(BTN = '1') then
            elsif(mode = "11") then
                mode <= "00";
                else
                **mode <= mode + "01";** -- the problem in the code
            end if;
         if(mode = "00") then
            LED <= '0';
            elsif(mode = "01") then
                LED <= '1';
                 elsif(mode = "10") then
                if(cnt = 33000000) then
                   LED <= not ledstatus;
                else
                   cnt := cnt + 1;
                end if;
             elsif(mode = "11") then
                if(cnt = 330000) then
                   LED <= not ledstatus;
                else
                   cnt := cnt + 1;
                end if;
       end if;
 end if;
 LED <= ledstatus; 

 end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `std_logic_vector` is just a vector of bits - it isn't necessarily a number.  The `+` operator has no meaning in this context.

You need to explicitly state that it is a number, in your case an unsigned number, and then convert it back to a `std_logic_vector`:

```
mode <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(mode) + 1);
```

When `mode` is equal to 3, adding 1 will make it wrap back round to 0.

There are plenty of other issues with your code but this will fix that immediate synthesis error.

Comment: First of all thank you for the answer :)
Tried to do it that way but for somereason it still doesn't work...

mode <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(unsigned (mode) + 1);

"Expression in type conversion to STD_LOGIC_VECTOR has 2 possible definitions in this scope, for example, UNSIGNED and std_logic_vector."

Comment: You probably have both these statements at the top of your file:
`use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;`

You should only use `numeric_std`

Comment: The code does not show what package is used for `unsigned` and general `std_logic` support, but I will suggest that `library ieee; use ieee.std_logic_1164.all; use ieee.numeric_std.all;` is used, and only this; the problem you describe in the comment may be due to using multiple and conflicting packages including for example `std_logic_unsigned`.

Comment: The comment interchange also demonstrates why including context clauses in VHDL example code can be necessary.